# Net библиотека для работы с hh

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

Доброго времени суток!

Возникла потребность срочно семенить работу, в связи с этим столкнулся с тем, что в день примерно 100 компаниям могу отправить резюме. И осенила идея - автоматически разослать свое резюме всем компаниям, которые только есть на сайте hh. Отобрать критериально, запустить цикл, отправка.

Проблема в том, что что-то не пойму, с чего начать, или схематично подскажите скелет того, что должен слать.

Возможно, есть библиотека net по работе с hh? Но смотрел, что-то не узрел...

Помогите кто чем может.

Comment: @Djuzi, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: @Виталина Я бы с радостью но пишет что, Недостаточно очков уважения 
для выполнения действия голос за.
Минимальная требуемая репутация - 15 (у вас 1).

Answer (score 2):

> Возникла потребность срочно семенить работу, в связи с этим столкнулся с тем что в день примерно 100 компаниям могу отправить резюме

Ну с такой активностью Вы и без бота работу найдете. )) Ну а если говорить серьезно, изучайте https://dev.hh.ru/ , там Вы найдете документацию по тому, как подобное задачу реализовать. В принципе, ничего сложного в этом нет, главное изучить API.

Весь принцип обычно сводиться к тому, что Вы отправляете определенный **http запрос**, содержащий необходимые параметры (эти параметры и что и куда отправлять обычно и описывается в API). Далее в ответ на Ваш запрос сервер возвращает ответ, который содержит запрашиваемую информацию. Ответ обычно идет либо в формате **json** или **xml**.